# Time complexity for finding all path of maximum length n starting from an input node

Tags: python, graph, networkx, depth-first-search

I wrote a simple algorithm which is a variant of DFS.

The idea is to find, in a directed graph, all paths of maximum length *n* starting from a given input node *u*.

Below there is the code in python:

```
def find_paths(G, u, n, n_recursive):
    paths = []
    if n_recursive == 0:
        return [[u]]
    if n_recursive < n:
        paths.append([u])
    for neighbor in G.neighbors(u):
        for path in find_paths(G, neighbor, n, n_recursive - 1):
            if u not in path:
                paths.append([u] + path)
    return paths
```

The output is simply a list of lists. In each internal list there is the ordered list of nodes crossed by that path.
Below there is an example of a graph and the output of the algorithm.

[image: graph]

Output for `find_paths(G=g, u=0, n=3, n_recursive=3)` (all paths of maximum lenght *3* from node *0*):

```
[[0, 1],
[0, 1, 2],
[0, 1, 2, 3],
[0, 1, 2, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 6],
[0, 2],
[0, 2, 3],
[0, 2, 3, 4],
[0, 2, 5],
[0, 2, 6]]
```

I know the complexity of DFS is O(|V|+|E|) (in the case of an adjacency list). How to compute the complexity of this algorithm? I honestly don't know where to start

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

> I know the complexity of DFS is O(|V|+|E|) (in the case of an adjacency list).

That's true when you want to visit *all* nodes of your graph. In that case the recursive function is potentially called multiple times from the toplevel, since the graph may have disconnected components.

But your use case is different, as you are only interested in paths that start at a given node, and so you would not have multiple calls from the top-level. This means the |V| does not play a role in the complexity. On the other hand, you allow edges to be visited multiple times, as they get visited via different paths. This means the output size will have a complexity that is not O(|E|).

Before analysing that further, first make an optimisation, as there is a bottleneck in this statement:

```
paths.append([u] + path)
```

This does not have a O(1) complexity, but O(length-of-path). This can be avoided. Instead append `u` at the *end* of `path` (mutating it), and then append that path to `paths`. This means that your result will have all paths in reversed order, but you can alter this order as a kind of post-processing. So the above code should change to:

```
path.append(u)
paths.append(path)
```

With this change, the time complexity of your algorithm is determined by the number of times these `append` calls happen, or in other words, it is equal to the size of the output.

The size of the output is not O(|E|). Take for instance this graph:

[image]

It has 19 nodes and 24 edges, but we could imagine it goes on like that, so that we have 3+1 nodes and 4 edges. Now let's say we want to have all the paths of length 2 starting at the left-most node, then we can at each "crossing" (and at the start node) make a choice between 2 options, so in total we have 2 paths, each with 2 + 1 nodes (i.e. these path sizes are 2). So the output size is O(2). Note that this represents the number of *node* references (integers) in the output, not just the number of paths.

Here is the code to create such "diamond" graphs:

```
import networkx
   
# Your function (not touched)
def find_paths(G, u, n, n_recursive):
    paths = []
    if n_recursive == 0:
        return [[u]]
    if n_recursive < n:
        paths.append([u])
    for neighbor in G.neighbors(u):
        for path in find_paths(G, neighbor, n, n_recursive - 1):
            if u not in path:
                paths.append([u] + path)  # inefficient -- see remarks
    return paths

def create_diamond_graph(k):
    G = networkx.DiGraph()
    for i in range(k):
        # 2-section path "above" from i  to  i+3
        G.add_edge(i*3, i*3+1)
        G.add_edge(i*3+1, i*3+3)
        # 2-section path "below" from i  to  i+3
        G.add_edge(i*3, i*3+2)
        G.add_edge(i*3+2, i*3+3)
    return G
    

# Main
k = 6  # Adjust this value to try other sizes
G = create_diamond_graph(k)
paths = find_paths(G, 0, 3*k, 2*k)

count = 0
for i, path in enumerate(paths):
    print(i, path)
    count += len(path)

print("number of paths", len(paths))
print("output size", count)
```

Here are the results for different values of

|  | number of edges | number of paths (max length 2) | number of node references |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | 11 |
| 2 | 8 | 13 | 47 |
| 3 | 12 | 28 | 151 |
| 4 | 16 | 61 | 423 |
| 5 | 20 | 125 | 1095 |
| 6 | 24 | 253 | 2695 |
| 7 | 28 | 509 | 6407 |

We can see how increasing  roughly doubles the number of possible paths of any length (max 2 length). The same goes for the output size. Asymptotically it doubles.

As  is O(|E|) in this specific category of graphs, the output size is here O(|E|2<sup>|E|/4</sup>), which also is the time complexity (the time needed to add each of these integers to paths in the output).

The reason for this exponential complexity is not your algorithm per se, but the specific goal you want to achieve.

Comment: The modification to the code sounds good, thanks!
About the time complexity, there is something I don't understand. In that case k=6, so we search for all the paths of maximum lenght 2k=12.
If the expected outuput size is O(|E|2^|E|), it would be milions of paths! If I run the algorithm on that graph I get 188 paths. Something like:
[[0, 1],
 [0, 1, 3],
 [0, 1, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 3, 4, 5],
 [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9],
 [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10],
 [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12],
 [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13],
 
and so on...

Comment: What is your question? No it would not be millions of paths. For one, this does not represent the number of paths, but the number of nodes in the output (so the number of integers). But note that 2^6 is just 64. And (2*6+1) * 2^6 is 832. That's not millions. I only considered paths with the *exact* length of  2. If we also consider that the output can contain all *prefix* paths of those paths, it will indeed be a lot more, but still not millions when  is 6.

Comment: BTW, when I run your code on this graph, I get 253 paths, and a total of 2695 integers in the output (representing the output size and the "work" needed to generate that output).  Do you still have a question about this?

Comment: I added the code to generate the example graph, and statistics to illustrate the complexity. I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: I still have some doubts:
1) You say that the output size is O(k2^k). But the numbers in the table are different. Am I missing something?!
2) Also, Isn't the upper bound O(|E|2^|E|) too big? 
3) In another type of graph, wherewe don't choice between 2 options, what happen?
Thanks

Comment: (1) Big O provides only an asymptotic *order* of magnitude. For instance, O(5n) = O(n/5) = O(10000000n+10000). (2) Why you think it is too big? The example proves that it can be that big. Note that the exponentiation only applies to the constant 2. So O(|E|(2^|E|)) (3) There are countless types of graphs. I chose the example to prove to you that it is *not* O(|E|). We can design examples where it is O(|E|3^|E|)... etc.

Comment: (1) got it. (2) Because for example, if we have 24 edges like the first example, the outputsize would be O(|E|(2^|E|)) = 24*(2^24) that is huge (instead of 2695) and the number of paths would be O(2^|E|) but it is just 253. (3) From your example I understood that it's not O(|E|), but is there a way to generalize the upper bound to a random graph without any kind of pattern? For example by replacing the 2 with the maximum out_degree of the network?

Comment: (2) You are right about this. Although  can be replaced by |E| in the coefficient of a big O expression, it is not anymore equivalent when doing that in the exponent. It should therefor be O(|E|2^(|E|/4)). I update this in my answer. (3), yes I think you could replace the base of the power with the maximum out degree. We can at least say the time complexity is exponential, which means it is "problematic" for an algorithm ;-)